# How to get to the specified element of vector<list<int> >?

Tags: c++, list, vector

I have code like this:

```
vector<list<int> > a(b);
```

Inside vector I have few lists, something like this:

{2,1}, {2,2}, {4,5} etc.

How to get to the specified element from the list inside that vector?

Comment: it is called indexing? `a[0][0]` is the value `2`, `a[0][1]` is the value `1`.. etc ([0][0] -> first 0 is the first element of the vector - first list, second 0 is the first element of that first list)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
The mcve can serve as a foundation to propose solutions to you.

Comment: Yes, a[0][0] is '2' but how to get to that value? I want to compare that value with, let's say '3' and check if it is greater or not. How to do that?

Comment: @Lucas - The same way you'd normally do a comparison.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - but it doesnt work. I got an error:  
no match for 'operator[]' in 'a.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::list<int>, std::allocator<std::list<int> > >(0u)[0]'|

Comment: `std::list` is not random-accessible.  You have to get an iterator to the beginning of the list and then increment it until you're at the element you want.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf Indexing does not work for `std::list` since it is a linked list

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I mixed between C# and C++, my bad :)

Comment: if your vector of lists is a guaranteed size every time it might be a good idea to consider using a list of structs or possibly a list of `std::pairs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an element from one of the lists, you need to first access the list containing the said element.

For example, to print every element greater than a certain variable (let's say 2) you could do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    std::vector<std::list<int> > vecList;
    int someVariable = 2;        

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        vecList.push_back(std::list<int> (i, i)); /* fill the vector with 4 lists {1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3, 3} {4, 4, 4, 4} */
    }

    /*this first loop will iterate over the content of the vector, not the content of the lists*/
    for (const auto& ls : vecList) {

        /*this will iterate over the content of each list in the vector*/
        for (auto head = ls.begin(), tail = ls.end(); head != tail; ++head) {
            if (*head > someVariable) { //*head is different from head
                std::cout << *head << std::endl;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

N.B: Read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and [`iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator).

Answer (score 1):

Lists are not directly accessible, so you'll need to iterate over each list.

Example:

```
std::vector< std::list< int > > a;
a.push_back( {1,2,3} );
a.push_back( {4,5,6} );
a.push_back( {7,8,9} );

// You cannot do this, as list does not have direct access.
// std::cout << a[0][0];

// You must access each element via iterator for each list.  This will print 1...9.
for( auto it = a[0].begin(); it!= a[0].end(); ++it ) std::cout << *it << std::endl;
for( auto it = a[1].begin(); it!= a[1].end(); ++it ) std::cout << *it << std::endl;
for( auto it = a[2].begin(); it!= a[2].end(); ++it ) std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::list<int> > arr;
for(const auto & i : arr) {
   auto first = i.begin();
   auto last = i.end();
   while (first != last) {
      std::cout << *first << std::endl;
      ++first;
   }
}
```

First of all I iterate throughout **arr**. Then on each step I have get i element (it is **std::list**) and I create iterator on first element of this list. Then I read all elements from this list and print them out. It is very easy to understand

Comment: I think that works! :) Can you explain me how it works, if possible? :)

Comment: @Lucas: First of all I iterate throughout arr. Then on each step I have get i element (it is std::list) and I create iterator on first element of this list. Then I read all elements from this list and print them out. It is very easy to understand

Comment: @Lucas: If it is an answer on your question, please mark it

Comment: @DenisKotov add those comments to the answer itself, it will help other to easily understand your suggestion...

Comment: @DenisKotov, your answer is great, but the most accurate for me was Nhatz's answer. But I have plussed your answer! :)